# Need help getting data from 3rd party program into web server database on a regular basis

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I am trying to build a data management system online using mysql/php/javascript/etc.
I have used Access for this in the past and it works great for the part I am struggling with.  Data comes from an HPLC (lab instrument), and the software that determines the results auto exports this as an excel file, but can also do csv.  After the export, the HPLC software runs a command file that opens access and runs a form which imports the file and places the data in the correct fields with proper identifiers.

I am now wanting to have all data on a web-based db.  This will allow for better access off-site, and an easier to maintain system, especially off site.  My problem is, I am not sure how to get the data from the HPLC to the database.

I think it may be possible to use mysql commands to upload the .csv file, but then to format and use proper table relations for the data, I am stuck!  How can I upload the data AND run a program to normalize?

Comment: Did look up the docs of *3rd party program* (HPLC)? It should be written there how the data feed can be customized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export to .csv.

Write an MySQL programm which

- creates a temporary table for your .csv input;
- uploads the data from the .csv file with the LOAD DATA statement;
- normalizes the data to your structured database tables by selecting them from the grand table with the csv data and inserting into your various tables.